# Scroll results of :hi

Tags: highlight

When I type `:hi` to see all the highlight groups, I only see as much as can fill the screen. How do I scroll through them?

```
:hi[ghlight]        List all the current highlight groups that have
                    attributes set.
```

To show more results, I have to re-run the command to decrease the text size, but I can’t scroll up:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're looking for. You can't scroll unless there's more than a page worth of output. If there was enough to scroll through it would say "More" at which point you could press `?` to see available commands.

Comment: Thanks.  I added more screenshots to prove that there are more results that aren’t being displayed.

Comment: Weird. Sounds like the pager isn't working for you. What do you get for `:set more?` Also, to rule out anything in your vimrc try `:hi` after launching Vim with `-u DEFAULTS`. (This is all to check Vim settings. It could also be something amiss in your terminal settings.)

Comment: Ah thanks, I see this works in `vim` and `nvim`, but not in `vimr`.  `:set more?` returns `more` in all cases, but the pager is broken in vimr, even with -u DEFAULTS.

Comment: What is `vimr`?

Comment: Wecome to [vi.se]! One option is to dump the output of the command into a (scratch) buffer. You can do that with a command such as `:put =execute('hi')`, which executes `:hi` but captures its output (that's the `execute()` part) and dumps it into the current buffer (`:put` with the expression-register `=`.)

Comment: @BLayer https://github.com/qvacua/vimr

Comment: Thanks @filbranden, this seems to hide the colors though.

Comment: @ShaunLebron Thanks. Never heard of it. You should report your issue to its devs. (TBH, I'm not sure it's even on-topic here since that part looks totally separate from vim/neovim, i.e. it's a totally new GUI implementation apparently.)

Comment: Are *other* commands scrollable? I’m inclined to disagree this is off-topic because vimr has enough of vim in it to qualify.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `j` `k` or arrow keys or `enter`; it's the same as the `less` command:

```
SPACE/d/j: screen/page/line down, b/u/k: up, q: quit
```

If you cannot move with any of these options, it's perhaps a bug in your vim or config.